# Using a presenter in a controller as if it was a model

Tags: activerecord, controller

I have this in my index action in a rails controller:

```
  def index
    if current_user.nil?
      @programs = Program.paginate(page: params[:page])
    else
      @programs = ProgramPresenter.all_for(current_user, Program).paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
    respond_with @programs
  end
```

`ProgramPresenter#all_for` returns an Array of program presenters. Naturally, the `.paginate()` from `will_paginate` doesn't work, because that's not a method that array implements. Yet I would like to have the rest of the controllers and views treat that 'array' similarly to the way I usually deal with collections of `ActiveRecord` models.

What's the best practice there?